# Oracle SQL weeks sales SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the sales data in terms of week:

```
ITEM   LOC      WEEK       SALES  
111    39    16/05/2015     10
222    39    16/05/2015     23
111    39    09/05/2015     13
222    39    09/05/2015     33
```

I want the sum of SALES column for the last 4 weeks.

So it comes like:

```
ITEM   LOC   4-WEEKS-SALES
111    39       23
222    39       56
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter for last four weeks and agregate:

```
select ITEM, LOC,sum(SALES) 
  from theTable 
 where WEEK > SYSDATE - ( 7 * 4 )
 group by ITEM,LOC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
 select ITEM,LOC,sum(SALES) '4-WEEKS-SALES'
    from tablename
    where Datepart(wk, WEEK)>=(Datepart(wk, Getdate())-4)
    Group by ITEM,LOC,Datepart(wk, WEEK)
```

Comment: Datepart function doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: Ya i know but it is sql query